# How to install cocos2dx on a mac?

Tags: eclipse, bash, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am following this tutorial to install cocos2d on a mac with eclipse.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Installation_guide_of_Android_ndk_r4b_development_environment

I get as far as installing the ndk and I get the following error below when I try and execute ndk-build. I have set my paths correctly so im not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
Davids-iMac:android-ndk-r8b davidcavanagh$ sh ndk-build
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file:       
/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8b/jni/Android.mk    
/Users/davidcavanagh/Documents/Development/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/add-    
application.mk:133: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this tutorial is much better than the original website.

All my environment setup is based on it.

http://gameit.ro/2012/01/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project-updated/